# How To Get A Generic Method To Implement An Interface

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace GenericMax
{
    class Program
    {
        interface Order
        {
            Boolean greaterThan(Order other);
        }

        class Thing : Order
        {
            public int value;

            public Thing(int value)
            {
                this.value = value; ;
            }

            public Boolean greaterThan(Order other)
            {
                // Convert the other to a thing so I can compare values
                return this.value > ((Thing)other).value;
            }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return "" + value;
            }

        }

        static TYPE max<TYPE>(TYPE a,TYPE b) //how would I implement Order
        {
            return a;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

How would I get the objects in the max method to implement the Order interface.
Ps: I know the logic of the max method is wrong.

For example in Java if I wanted to get max to implement Order it would be like:

```
<TYPE implements Order> TYPE max(TYPE a, TYPE b)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this syntax:

```
static T max<T>(T a, T b) where T: Order
{
    // Your codes.
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much! @mshsayem